# Episerver- Client validation not working when using custom attribute in specialized property

Tags: episerver

I have a specialized property in episerver named Location with a below given structure:

```
public virtual string Name{ get; set; }

public virtual string City { get; set; }

[RegularExpression("^(\\+\\s?)?((?<!\\+.*)\\(\\+?\\d+([\\s\\-\\.]?\\d+)?\\)|\\d+)([\\s\\-\\.]?(\\(\\d+([\\s\\-\\.]?\\d+)?\\)|\\d+))*(\\s?(x|ext\\.?)\\s?\\d+)?$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone Number")]
public virtual string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

The phone property is not a required one & the given regex handles it fine. With the regex, validation kicks in the next instant.

[image]

**Issue**
Now when i create a custom attribute with the same regex in it ,the validation only kicks in when the page which includes this specialized location property is published.

[image]

[image]

Could some one shed some light on why client validation kicks in with regex & not with custom attribute?

Regards.